# How does the get method in Future works in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Below is the piece of code  that submits a job.. Let's say I have 3 threads running. how does the get method wait and obtain the appropriate thread results.

```
Future<?> result = threadPool.submitTasks(new Callable<T>() {
            public T call() throws Exception {
                // do something
        }

});
anyType = (T) result.get();
```

Or Lets say I have Task A resulted 1 and Task B resulted 2.. When it comes to get method, what is the guarantee that it returns the correct values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your submitted task (in this case the Callable) is wrapped into the instance of the returned `Future`. In essence, the `Future` is *directly related to the task it was created for*, and not any other task.

Internally, when calling `get`, the future will attempt to acquire a lock that it shares in common with its wrapped task. Once acquired, it then queries the status of the task in order to determine what to do next:

1. Throw an exception if the `Future` was cancelled, or if the underlying task generated an exception
2. Otherwise, return the result that was generated by the task.

This is *broadly* how it works, there are several implementations of `Future` and they all have different internal logic.

Comment: Exactly. I am catching the ExecutionException and CancelledException. I just wanted to make sure there are no concurrency issues with the Future get method. you clarified this.  Thanks a lot. I guess you   meant get not take in the 2nd paragraph of your answer.

Comment: Oops, yes I meant `get`, not `take`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming there is a guarantee they will receive the correct output. This is a question of implementing [Thread safe code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Often, to make an implementation thread safe, you will lock it from use with some sort of flag. This will indicate to other threads that they can not use it.